# How to specify the dimensions for an element to take the full window in HTML

Tags: html, css

I want to specify an element which will take the full browser window. So I wrote this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">    
</head>
<body>

<div id="background" style="position: absolute; height: 100%; width: 100%; "> 
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

But the problem is that there is always a scrollbar on right side which implies the height of this element is larger than the actual height of the browser window.

Am I missing anything here?

Comment: [No `padding`/`margin`](http://jsfiddle.net/n3kveetp/), [with `padding`/`margin`](http://jsfiddle.net/n3kveetp/).

Comment: The first link is the same as the answer you selected as correct below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The body element has a default margin. You can remove it with :

```
body {
    margin:0;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/moak9ewc/)**

Comment: Perfect, that is the solution  I want. More importantly, you tried it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The scrollbars may be as a result of the margins/padding on the element. Try this:

**css:**

```
#background {
    width:100VW;
    Height:100VH;
    Margin:0;
    Padding:0;
}
/*you don't need to set it, but you can, if you want:*/
Body, HTML {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
```

If you mean the entire *window/screen*, not the *viewport*, then it is not possible, apart from using the fullscreen API.

**Fullscreen API Example:**

```
function launchIntoFullscreen(element) {
    if(element.requestFullscreen) {
        element.requestFullscreen();
    } else if(element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
        element.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if(element.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
        element.webkitRequestFullscreen();
    } else if(element.msRequestFullscreen) {
        element.msRequestFullscreen();
    }
}
launchIntoFullscreen(document.getElementById("background"));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: No luck. Did not work. Here is what I have tried:
<div id="background" style="position: absolute; height: 100%; width: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;">

Comment: You also need to clear the margin on the body element. See my answer.